# sencha touch :: adding some text before a list

Tags: html, list, sencha-touch

how could I add some html-text inside a list before the list-entries. the text has scroll up with the list!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should it be like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/p5K4q/28/

```
new Ext.Application({
    launch: function() {
       var panel =  new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            id:'thePanel',
            layout: 'vbox',
             scroll:'vertical'
        });

    var list = new Ext.List({
        id :'theList',
        itemTpl : '{firstName} {lastName}',
        store: store1,
        width: '100%',
        scroll:false
    });


var smallPanel = new Ext.Panel({layout: 'auto',width:'100%',height:50,style:'background-color:darkgreen;color:white',html:"Hello I'm the panel"});
    panel.items.add(smallPanel);
    panel.items.add(list);
    panel.doLayout();               
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, the scoll:false/scroll:vertical-combination was the right switch, I guess. thx!!!!